# Pattern.matches vs string.matches("regex")

Tags: java, regex

What is better performance wise:
`string.matches("regex")`
or
`Pattern.compile("regex").matches(string).find()` 
 ?

What I am referring to is matching through `String.java`'s `matches()`, or API in `Pattern.java`

Comment: Cannot compare performance of apples vs. oranges. `matches()` and `find()` is not the same operation. --- Also, you code won't compile, since it should be `matcher()` between `compile()` and `find()`, not `matches()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Implementation of `String.matches(String regex)`:

```
public boolean matches(String regex) {
    return Pattern.matches(regex, this);
}
```

Implementation of `Pattern.matches(String regex, CharSequence input)`:

```
public static boolean matches(String regex, CharSequence input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    return m.matches();
}
```

**Conclusion:** `str.matches(regex)` is **exactly the same** as `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).matches()`.

*Note: Same as `matches()`, not same as `find()`.*

Using `Pattern.compile()` is better/required if:

- You need access to the `Matcher`.
  E.g. you need the result of capture groups.
- You do the same `matches(regex)` call many times.
  Only compiling the `regex` pattern once improves performance.

Comment: The difference is that the Pattern can be compiled once and as it is theradsafe (only the Pattern, not the Matcher) you can reuse the Pattern. This reduced object creation and garbage collecting and is  faster if you execute it a lot of times. unless you have several 100'000 of subsequent calls, it probably does not really matter.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you will be reusing the regex.  If you do, it is better to compile it only once.  The `matches` function in `String` is defined in terms of `Pattern.matches`:

```
public boolean matches(String regex) {
    return Pattern.matches(regex, this);
}
```

Snippet from [openJDK7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java)